# Edge browser error 'Hmm, we can't reach this page' loading localhost address

Tags: browser, hosts-file, microsoft-edge

Microsoft Edge presenting error message 'Hmm, we can't reach this page' loading localhost address.

Loopback flag is checked.

```
Address mapped in host file
127.0.0.1   www.desenv
```

OS: Windows 10 - Build 10240

In Google Chrome work fine.

**Whitout proxy works. But using the proxy exceptions does not.**

What is happening?

Comment: What happens if you add .com to your entry?

Comment: It's a alias defined in my host file (c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts), not a external url. He is pointing to local address.

Comment: Yes, I know that.  He can still put www.desenv.com into the hosts file and it will work (although might not solve this particular problem).  I'm asking to try to narrow down the cause.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but whitout proxy works. And using the proxy exceptions does not.

Comment: So then i'd say the issue is with your proxy server, not edge.  If the proxy is on a different computer, it won't see changes to the hosts file on the computer with Edge.

Comment: I read that this appears to be  related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30334289/cant-open-localhost-in-microsoft-edge-project-spartan-in-windows-10-preview

Comment: After a few windows updates did not occur more errors.

Comment: Closing as a system update wiped the issue away

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that I have all the latest Windows 10 update for my machine. Afeter looking online, I found a work-a-round at a [MS Tech Q/A](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/246298d8-52c1-4440-8d7f-05329d50e653/edge-browser-hosts-file?forum=win10itprogeneral). The problem seems to be with how MS Edge works with the hosts file; If I change my single word alias to a something [FQDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) qualified, it works, for example:

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

```
# Does not work for MS Edge
127.0.0.1    kshabazz

# Works for MS Edge
127.0.0.1    loc.kshabazz.net
```

So I had to change the host name in the host file and my web server (Nginx 1.9.5), then everything worked again.

Comment: not true. I have FQDN but it doesn't work http://dev-subdmain.maindomain.com